# How to set attribute to element that is dynamically created?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm getting response from a `$.post` and it contains elements. The element contains `<a>` and `<img>`.

I want to prevent the `<a>` element from doing it's default functions when it is clicked and I want to disabled the `draggable` option for both the element `<a>` and `<img>`.

Using `.on()` you can define your function once, and it will execute for any dynamically added elements.

**E.g: These will prevent anchor element from doing it's default function when it is clicked.**
 
`$('body').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
   "use strict";
   e.preventDefault();
});`

How about setting the attribute for it? The below code doesn't work for dynamic element.
`$('a').attr('draggable', false);`
`$('img').attr('draggable', false);`

Comment: You'll have to wait until it's parsed into an object or added to the DOM to alter its attributes.

Comment: Can you show are you are adding the dynamic content to the page?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are adding that response element somewhere into your markup.

**The Markup**

```
<div id="container">
    <!--Add dynamic element here-->
</div>
```

**The JS**

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
   "use strict";
   e.preventDefault();
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ServerAddress,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#container').html(data); //1: Insert the element into your markup
        $('#container a').attr('draggable', false); //2: The element is ready to add some attribute
        $('#container img').attr('draggable', false); //2: The element is ready to add some attribute
    }
});
```

You just need to wait until it's parsed into an object.